# Pullback of homotopy on differential forms?

Tags: homotopy-theory, differential-forms, pullback

I am working through a proof in differential forms that if the curves $c_0$ and $c_1$ are homotopic and the homotopy $F:[0,1]^2\to U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is $C^1$ and $\omega^1$ is closed $1-$form on $U$, then the line integrals along $c_0$ and $c_1$ coincide.

In the proof it is stated but not explained why $F|_{(0,s)}^* \omega^1 = 0$ after it states that $F(0,s) = c_0(0) = c_1(0)$ is independent of $s$. The only thing I can think is that $F(0,s)$ is constant and so its derivative is $0$ for all $s\in[0,1]$. But I can't extend to why this will make any 1-form uniformly equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The general statement is that if $I \subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval, and if $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^n$ is a constant path, then for any $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb R^n$ we have $\gamma^* \omega = 0$. To see why, pick $s \in I$, and pick a tangent vector $v \in T_s I \approx \mathbb R$ and let's evaluate: 
$$\gamma^* \omega(v)= \omega(D\gamma|_s(v)) = \omega(\vec 0) = 0
$$
The fact used here is that since $\gamma$ is constant, the linear transformation $D\gamma|_s : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ is zero, because the velocity vector $\gamma'(s)$ is the zero vector and so $D_\gamma|_s(v) = v \cdot \gamma'(s) = v \cdot \vec 0 = \vec 0$.

Comment: But why is $\omega(0)=0$

Comment: If you look at $F$ along the interval $J=\{0\} \times [0,1]$ (with the interval parametrized by $s$), then $F|_J^*\omega$ will be some function times $ds$. But as $s$ varies, the function is constant, and a constant function pulls back any form to the $0$-form (after all, each coordinate function is a constant function, say $c$, and $c^*dx_i = d(x_i\circ c) = dc_i = 0$).

Comment: $\omega$ is a linear transformation (at each point). Plug the zero vector $\vec 0$ into any linear transformation and you get $0$.

Comment: I've added a few symbols to my notation to clarify what's a vector.